# How do I represent it with date for "dd MMM yyyy", means "11 JUN 2019"?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have date string like this "11 June, 2019 16:35:21". When I try to convert the string to NSDate it returns nil.

```
NSString str =@"11 June, 2019 16:35:21";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
NSString *string = [[formatter stringFromDate:date] uppercaseString];
```

Is there any other way to convert it? Or where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need a date format that actually matches the format of the date in the string. And if you are trying to convert from one format to another then you need two formats.

Comment: just replace "dd MMM yyyy" with "dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use date format as like

```
 NSString str =@"11 June, 2019 16:35:21";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] 
                 initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
 // input dateformat      @"11 June, 2019 16:35:21";
[formatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
// output dateformat for e.g @"11 Jun 2019 
   [formatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *string = [[formatter stringFromDate:date] uppercaseString];
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the locale to en_US_POSIX.

Comment: @rmaddy - sure , I will add

Answer (score 0):

Karthik is right, first, you have to convert date string with @"dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss" format to NSDate, then convert it to your desired format @"dd MMM yyyy".
Hope so following code'll work.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] 
             initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *str = @"11 June, 2019 16:35:21";
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:str];
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *string = [[formatter stringFromDate:date] uppercaseString];
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer. You should select the answer by @Anbu.Karthik which is more correct and was posted first.

Comment: oh I didn't know. I read your comment then I saw this one. I tried the code and it worked. But if you suggest then I will select Karthik's answer.

Comment: @SomoyDasGupta You definitely should use the other answer. Setting the locale is important, otherwise it will fail for many users.

Answer (score 0):

The NSDateFormatter uses Unicode Technical Standard.

this site has a great documentation: 
[Date_Format_Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

e.g. "11 June, 2019 16:35:21" can be parsed with:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss"]
```